# Traversing Expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees, traversal

Is there any possibility to traverse Expression instance in .NET?

I mean:
i have Expression/Expresstion> instance generated in external code.
is there any possibility to see what is in there ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

The easiest option is to inherit the [`ExpressionVisitor` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx).
A [.Net 3.5 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521.aspx) is also available.